# Register data into Many-to-Many Relation Table

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jhipster

I have 'Course' and 'Student' entities. They have many-to-many relation. So, i have COURSE_STUDENT(contains 'student_id' and 'course_id' columns) table. I want to register students to courses with a button.(For example; a student lists courses and click Register button to register a specific course).
When i want to create new courses, i use courseRepository and courseMapper which comes from JHipster by default.
But i don't have repository and mapper files for COURSE_STUDENT. Because it is not actually a main entity. It is created for many-to-many relation.
How can i register students to courses?

Git repo:https://github.com/canberkizgi/monolithic-mucs

My course entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Course implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
private String title;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@ManyToOne
private Instructor instructor;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@JoinTable(name = "course_student",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="courses_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="students_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
```

Student entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Student implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(unique = true)
private User user;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "students")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();
```

For example; Createcourse function with Mapper and Repository

```
    @PostMapping("/courses")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<CourseDTO> createCourse(@Valid @RequestBody CourseDTO courseDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to save Course : {}", courseDTO);
    if (courseDTO.getId() != null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert(ENTITY_NAME, "idexists", "A new course cannot already have an ID")).body(null);
    }
    Course course = courseMapper.toEntity(courseDTO);
    course = courseRepository.save(course);
    CourseDTO result = courseMapper.toDto(course);
    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/courses/" + result.getId()))
        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
        .body(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is owned by the course entity. Thats because on the student side the `@ManyToMany` annotation has a `mappedBy` attribute. This means, that the database will reflect the set in the course. You need to add students to that set to save the relationship. That change needs to be done within a transaction.

That being said it would probably be best to follow DDD here. I would create a `registerTo` method in the student class that would take the course as a parameter. I would then call `this.courses.add(course)` and `course.getStudents().add(this)` in that method.